Vault logs continously spamming no TLS config found for ALPN: ALPN=
I am using external DNS for api address and cluster address.However i getting lot of warning messages continuously and causing the pod to go Out of Memory.
These external endpoints are NLB listening on TCP ports 8200 and 8201.
Is it necessary to use public DNS for cluster endpoint?
How to resolve this log spam?
Any help is appreciated.
Api Address: https://vault.abc.com:8200
Cluster Address: https://vault.abc.com:8201
Config:
ui = true

  listener "tcp" {
    tls_disable = 0
    address = "[::]:8200"
    cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
    tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tl-tls/server.crt"
    tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tl-tls/server.key"
    #tls_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tl-tls/ca.crt"
    telemetry {
      unauthenticated_metrics_access = "true"
    }
  }

Error:
2024-06-18T03:16:00.384Z [WARN] core.cluster-listener: no TLS config found for ALPN: ALPN=
2024-06-18T03:16:00.682Z [WARN] core.cluster-listener: no TLS config found for ALPN: ALPN=
2024-06-18T03:16:00.961Z [WARN] core.cluster-listener: no TLS config found for ALPN: ALPN=
2024-06-18T03:16:01.497Z [WARN] core.cluster-listener: no TLS config found for ALPN: ALPN=
2024-06-18T03:16:01.675Z [WARN] core.cluster-listener: no TLS config found for ALPN: ALPN=

